# References about the mathematics of mazes or labyrinths

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I am looking for references on mazes or labyrinths. I prefer books, but research articles are welcome, too. I am looking for the mathematical point of view of mazes, not their history or development.

Any book that has a chapter about mazes is welcome, too (for example, a graph theory book with a chapter about mazes).

So far, I've found [*Mazes for Programmers*](https://pragprog.com/book/jbmaze/mazes-for-programmers), which talks about how to code mazes.

Comment: For me its hard to point you a deep reference, because mathematically a labyrinth  usually is considered as a plane graph. We may look for paths in this graph: [Eulerian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), a [shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) between two given vertices.Less abstract consideration of labyrinths is in 
recreational mathematics.

Comment: For instance,  in Martin Garnder’s “Mathematical puzzles and diversions” is a small chapter devoted to them, but I have only a Russian translation of this book.

Comment: The Wolfram Demonstrations Project has [a few dozen entries for "maze"](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=maze). I don't know how deep any of them goes into theory (that's not really what the Demonstrations are for), but Demonstrations often include citations that could be helpful. You might also search Ed Pegg's [MathPuzzle.com](http://mathpuzzle.com) for entries about mazes. I agree that Martin Gardner is also a good source for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Some pointers:

- In *The Topology of Roman Mosaic Mazes* (1992), author Anthony Philips discusses the topology of the 46 mazes that were 'well-preserved enough to be intelligible'. He finds that that these fall into 25 distinct topological types, which in turn can be built up out of seven elementary submazes. [Link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1575858#metadata_info_tab_contents)
- In his 1987 article *Creating Life: Or, does Architecture Determine Anything?*, Hillier et al. define the notion of intelligibility for spatial layouts, including mazes. [Link](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/101/1/hillier-etal-1987-creating-life.pdf)
- This notion has been explored more in subsequent papers, including [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alain-Chiaradia/publication/309411103_In_The_Intelligibility_Maze_of_Space_Syntax-a_Space_Syntax_Analysis_of_Toy_Models_Mazes_and_Labyrinths/links/5831e37c08aef19cb819ace2/In-The-Intelligibility-Maze-of-Space-Syntax-a-Space-Syntax-Analysis-of-Toy-Models-Mazes-and-Labyrinths.pdf) by Zhang et al.  (2013)
- Erik Demaine et al. look into the concept of *origami mazes* in the following 2011 [article](https://scripts.mit.edu/~jasonku/pdf/MAZEFOLDING_ORIGAMI5.pdf)
- Information on creating reconfigurable mazes can be found in this 2014 [article](https://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2014/bridges2014-167.pdf) by Craig S. Kaplan
- Finally, there's an introduction to the mathematics of mazes in the following [overview](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343615560_The_Mathematics_of_Mazes) (2020) by Hollis Williams. It discusses mazes from both a graph theoretical / topological point of view, and from the perspective of recreational mathematics